# Google signin: Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain (javascript web app)

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin

I'm using the Google signin Javascript API (that is, the `gapi-signin-button`) on a webapp. The app is served by a gulp server, binding to `0.0.0.0`. The login process works when I develop locally, but when I run on a remote server and access the page via the public IP, I get the following signin error:

```
Error: invalid_request
Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.
```

I have both `localhost:PORT` and `SERVER_IP:PORT` in my Authorized JavaScript origins. Other SO answers have said I should be binding to `localhost` instead of other interfaces, but that doesn't apply here since if I bind to localhost the server can't be accessed remotely. What do?

Comment: Have you figured out what causes this? I am having the same problem and have gotten no answers, as have you. This is driving me insane; I've even called Google and they just tell me to ask the question on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google: Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain NOT on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem and just figured it out. You can't use numerical ip addresses (like http://0.0.0.0) as redirect uris in Google. It has to be an actual url, like http://mycompany.com.

Comment: So can't we use auth2 in numerical ip addresses?