# Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain. google auth error in ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am getting the error while using google authentication in my web app, everything was working fine but suddenly it started showing the error "Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain." when I am trying to login to my web app.

I am hosting the web app in AWS EC2 instance and I have configured the ec2 public DNS name in my google API manager.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google: Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain NOT on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh)

Answer (score 0):

When you set up OAuth for your application, you will need a DNS name that refers to your instance's IP address. You can use the xip.io service to get one; this is a public service offered for free by Basecamp. For instance, the DNS name can be 54.84.49.254.xip.io.