# Google: Permission denied to generate login hint

Tags: javascript, google-authentication

I am trying to create a Google sign-in and getting the error:

Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain

Request Details

- redirect_uri=https://www.DOMAIN_FOR_REDIRECT.com/main-page/
- response_type=permission id_token
- scope=email profile openid
- openid.realm=
- client_id=XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
- ss_domain=https://www.SOURCE_DOMAIN_WITH_GOOGLE_BUTTON.com
- fetch_basic_profile=true
- siwebsdk=2

Domains

- https://www.DOMAIN_FOR_REDIRECT.com/main-page/
- https://www.SOURCE_DOMAIN_WITH_GOOGLE_BUTTON.com
  added to

> Authorized JavaScript origins

There is no restrictions for redirect_uri in docs
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#request-parameter-redirect_uri

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig

Auth code example hosted on domain https://www.SOURCE_DOMAIN_WITH_GOOGLE_BUTTON.com :

```
gapi.auth2
    .init({
        client_id: `XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com`,
        scope: 'profile',
        ux_mode: 'redirect',
        redirect_uri: 'https://www.DOMAIN_FOR_REDIRECT.com/main-page/'
    })
```

Comment: according to that doc, you have to `'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY', 'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',` ... *where is your api key* ? (assuming `${id}` correctly replaced)

Comment: ..i mean you should NOT post it, but consider to add it to "init object"... :)

Comment: in https://myaccount.google.com/security  check if Less secure app access is set to ON

Comment: I believe that scope should be a URL that Google provides according to the requested api.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see `ux_mode` anywhere in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#request-parameter-redirect_uri) you provided.

In the docs on [gapi.auth2 ClientConfig](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig) I can see the variables you refer to. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh) sheds some light on the fact that the URI must be a full URL, but you can work some magic to get the ip address to work on private network.

Can you verify that you've added your URL to your authorized JavaScript origins, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47300882/992432)?