# Javascript origin Google Oauth with local address 192.168.1.xx

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

i need to set the trusted origin in Google Oauth authentication with an address: 192.168.1.5.
It works with localhost, but with 192.168.1.5 the message is

{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain."
}

i have tried also with .xip.io service, eg: 192.168.1.5.xip.io but error remains!

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020374/google-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-not-on-localh). Maybe you are using an IP address (as in `http://175.132.64.120`) for the redirect uri, as this was a test site on the live server, and Google only accepts actual urls (as in `http://mycompany.com` or `http://localhost`) as redirect uris. Use a uri (`http://something.com`) instead of an ip address (`http://123.45.678`) in the redirectURIs or Javascript Origins depending on what you need it for. They won't allow ip addresses, and there's nothing that can be done about it. If you're debugging it on your local computer just use `http://localhost:<port number>`. You can also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611572/google-signin-permission-denied-to-generate-login-hint-for-target-domain-javas).